# AngularJs Services singleton within ng-app directive?

Tags: angularjs

Angular app says services are singleton across application. I hope  here application mean html element with ng-app
directive.

so if i have two pages in my webapp with separate ng-app directive, and they both call service1(included in js file)
My understanding is service1 will be instantiated twice for pages. So it mean services are singleton with in scope of
given ng-app directive. Is that correct ?

consider two html pages includes js file containing service1

```
//page 1
<html ng-app>
// call Service1
</html>
```

Second page

```
//page 2
<html ng-app>
// call Service1
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct.

**Extra Info**

Whenever a page with AngularJS code is loaded, the whole AngularJS lifecycle happens from beginning to end.

> 1. Bootstrap
> 2. Compilation
> 3. Runtime

For more information, click here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2271482&seqNum=3
http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/